# how to use graphics2d with embed fonts in iText

Tags: java, fonts, itext, graphics2d

I am using graphics2d's drawString method to show strings in iText. However I cannot use embed-ed fonts to graphics2d, when i try to call graphics2d's setFont method, it requires java.awt.font instead of itextpdf.text.Font. How can I use embed fonts to graphics 2d ?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).